# Can't figure out how to get makefile to work with just a .asm file and a .o file

Tags: assembly, makefile

```
FILES = lab.o

OBJS = $(FILES:.o=.c)
ASMS = $(FILES:.c=.s)

all:    lab

lab: $(OBJS)
    gcc -o lab $(OBJS)

asmfiles:   $(ASMS)

%.o:    %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@

%.s:    %.c
    gcc -S $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.s
```

When running make clean, then make, I keep getting

```
make: *** No rule to make target `lab', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

I've tried using both lab, lab.asm. lab.o for the files. I can't find much info on using a makefile without .c file.

Pretty stumped.

Comment: Are you sure that you want your *object* files to be named with the ending `.c`, and is your source file really named with the ending `.o`? Any why go through the step of assembly files? Compilers today (and since very far back) have been able to generate object files directly. And there is a rule for C source files to generate object files, the assembly file rule is not needed.

Comment: Wild gues `.PHONY: clean` before `clean:`

Comment: So you've got an assembly language file named `lab.asm`? Your makefile doesn't specify what to do with a `.asm` file. Also, you haven't said anything about which assembler your code is written for.

Comment: The value of `$(OBJS)` is `lab.c`, that's probably not what you want. The value of `$(ASMS)` is `lab.o`, that's probably also not what you want. The prerequisite of the `lab` target is `lab.c`. Do you have a `lab.c` file in the current directory?

Comment: no .c. I need to somehow setup the makefile to build the asm file.

Comment: Without knowing which assembler your code is written for that's going to be very hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your makefile doesn't specify what to do with `.asm` files, nor does it say anything about using NASM as the assembler.

Here's a small example makefile that would build an executable named `lab` from the assembly file `lab.asm` using NASM as the assembler and LD (from the GNU binutils) as the linker. Feel free to modify/expand it as necessary:

```
TARGET = lab
FILES = lab.asm

OBJS = $(FILES:.asm=.o)
NASM = nasm
ASM_FLAGS = -f elf64
LD = ld

all : $(TARGET)

lab: $(OBJS)
    $(LD) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS)

%.o : %.asm
    $(NASM) $(ASM_FLAGS) -o $@ $<
```